# Paypal! Get payment id by token using PHP SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have paypal response like paypalresponse?success=false&**token=EC-8VH36191PU035730M**. I need to get payment id by this token if payment is failed. Using PayPal PHP SDK.

Comment: Why you don't use the provided paymentId, or isn't it provided in case of error?

Answer (score 0):

If the payment is unsuccessful you will not receive a transaction id. You should receive a Correlation ID along with the error message.

From the PayPal Developer Site:

> A non-successful response can contain more than one error number and message. NVP Error fields start with L_ERRORCODEn, where n, starting from 0, identifies a unique error in the response. There are two messages for each error number, L_SHORTMESSAGEn and L_LONGMESSAGEn, where n corresponds with n in L_ERRORCODEn. The equivalent SOAP error fields are: ErrorCode, ShortMessage and LongMessage.

[Handling Error Messages with Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#id84fb96ff-148f-421c-8cde-b9f9583091ca)
[How to recover from Funding Failure](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/#errorcode)